# Python Selenium finds button but doesn´t click on it

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I have some HTML-Code. In this Section is stored a button, I want to click on the button with the Selenium module of Python. My problem ist, that Selenium can find the button, but doesn´t click on it.

The HTML Section:

```
<div id="button" class="buttons reviewButton">

<input track-submit="" value="Weiter" id="confirmButtonTop" class="btn full confirmButton continueButton" validate-submit="onPay()" type="submit">

</div>
```

My Python-code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("id('confirmButtonTop')").submit()
```

Comment: Did you try using `.click()`?

Comment: Yeah, i tried using .click()

Comment: What about `driver.find_element_by_id('confirmButtonTop').click()` ?

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the <div> instead of the <input>? Are you getting any output or anything?

Comment: Please add a full minimum working example, which would help people help you.

Comment: how do you know it finds the button? what happens?
Also since you use id, why not try `driver.find_element_by_id("confirmButtonTop").submit()`?

Comment: What does "doesn't click on it" mean? Error message or ? Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: That's not a valid XPath so I'm assuming that's the issue. You should probably spend some time reading some Selenium and locator tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='confirmButtonTop']").click()
```

Comment: Please don't use XPath to click on something simple like an ID.